# How to monitor tomcat cluster through java melody tool

Tags: apache2, tomcat7, monitoring

I would like to monitor my server health. I have deployed my web app in tomcat 7. I am using 4 instances of Tomcat 7 running on the same machine. individually I am unable to monitor each tomcat instance. But how to monitor all tomcat at one time. I mean Apache Server is in the front end and redirecting all the requests to tomcat 7 instances. I am using load balancer. How to monitor it. Please suggest.

Thanks